# Як правильно перекласти multiple lights?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни, словосполучення

Працюю з перекладом статті щодо програмування комп'ютерної графіки.

Є таке поняття в літературі - **multiple lights**

Воно значить, що є декілька джерел світла, які освітлюють якусь поверхню.
Не можу знайти якийсь адекватний варіант перекладу даного словосполучення.
Є варіант **множинне світло**, але якось вухо ріже.

От як це виглядає:
[image]

Comment: Як щодо "більш, ніж одне світло"?

Comment: Як щодо *полівекторне/багатовекторне світло*?

Comment: Дякую, але багатовекторне світло якось ускладнює розуміння того, що це за таке світло.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Відмінювання множини до світло [тут](http://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D1%C2%B2%D2%CB%CE). Варіанти перекладу multiple [тут](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=multiple&dicts=all&highlight=on).

- Декілька світл - не підходить, бо світл може бути 1000 і більше;
- Багато світл - не підходить, бо світл може бути лише 2;
- Комбінація світл - хотілось би питоміше слово;
- Складене світло - це може позначати зовсім інше поняття;
- Множинне світло - гм... подібно до [множинне спадкування](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F).

Comment: `Декілька світл` -> Декілька джерел світла!

Comment: @Glutton хочеться уникнути додатквого слова, коли з контексту зрозуміло про що йдеться

Comment: Згідно словників англійської мови ([оксфорського](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/light) ), [макмілановського](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/light_1) та [мерріем-вебстерового](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/light)) light не лише світло, а й джерело світла. Тому "Декілька джерел світла" цілком прийнятно, як на мене, хоча і не так лаконічно як в оригіналі. Можно вигадати конструкцію типу "Багатоджерельне світло/освітлення"

Comment: @Odmin я з вами згоден щодо перекладу, але тут те, що йдеться про джерела світла зрозуміло з контексту.

Comment: @Yola, фокус в тому, що в данному випадку це ще й назва розділу, тобто читач бачить назву але не бачить контексту.

Comment: @Odmin гадаю читач дуже швидко зорієнтується. Якби виникала якась двозначність, то ще можна було б подумати, а так додавати третє слово не хочеться. По собі знаю, що скорочую як можу якщо сенс не втарчається.

Answer (score 11):

Можливо "складне (комплексне) освітлення". Судячи з кількох статтей multiple lights - це програмування освітлення сцени/об'єкта масивом джерел світла. Причому інтенсивність, тип та положення цих джерел у масиві, здається, нічим не обмежується.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Будь ласка, завжди додавайте до ваших відповідей посилання на поважні джерела. Відповіді, які базуються лише на особистій думці авторів, не заохочуються, тому що вони є запрошенням до спростувань (також голослівних).

Comment: Це словосполучення реально використовується: «Піднявши горизонт і застосувавши складне освітлення, автори подали зображення контражуром на тлі неба» [[1\]](//books.google.com/books?id=bJsxAAAAIAAJ&q=складне+освітлення), «Ще одним важливим моментом є комплексне освітлення кухонної зони» [[2\]](//mebleva-hata.com.ua/recomendations/) — хоча частина використань щодо встановлення реальних джерел світла, а не комп'ютерної графіки, але, як на мене, це не має значення (тим паче, що деякі вжитки, здається, саме про графіку, хоч і не комп'ютерну). Тому це найкраща відповідь, як на мене.

Comment: Спочатку я хотів прокоментувати, що "multiple lights" з мого досвіду не сталий вираз/термін в англійській літературі і зазвичай є просто вичерпною назвою для розділу з довідників, але "складне освітлення" і "комплексне освітлення" дійсно звучать як типові інженерні терміни (та ж форма, що і "складне випромінення", "складний рух") що описують багатокомпонентні системи.

Answer (score 4):

Думаю перекладати потрібно не як світло, а саме як освітлення - це трохи різні речі. *Освітлення з кількох* (двох, трьох чи більше - потрібне вказати) *ракурсів*. Слово ракурс звичайно ж іншомовного походження, але цілком вжитнє у вкраїнській мові. Можна також перекласти як *освітлення із кількох джерел*... цілком українське, але здається не зовсім точно передає зміст.

Comment: Автор перекладає статтю з компʼютерної графіки. Це означає, що відповідь має містити пояснення, чому саме цей варіант підходить авторові запитання. Наприклад, підійшли б посилання на те, як цей термін використовують *інші статті з компʼютерної графіки.* Або на загальні словники української мови.